# Task renaming with load-grunt-config

Tags: gruntjs

I have grunt project with 'watch' task from *grunt-contrib-watch* and I want to rename it to something like 'delta' and call it in context of my own 'watch' task with another my tasks. Also i'm using *load-grunt-config*. My configuration:

**package.json**

```
{
  "author": "Boris",
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "repository": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.8.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "load-grunt-config": "^0.19.1"
  }
}
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  require('load-grunt-config')(grunt);

  grunt.renameTask('watch', 'delta');
}
```

**grunt/aliases.js**

```
module.exports = {
  watch: [
      'copy',
      'delta'
  ]
};
```

**grunt/watch.js**

```
module.exports = {
  options: {
      livereload: true
  },
  js: {
    files: [
        '<%= app_files.js %>'
    ],
    tasks: ['copy']
  }
}
```

But i've got error:

```
Warning: Task "watch" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

It seems that it is because of

```
grunt.renameTask('watch', 'delta');
```

after config loading, but from the other hand i can't insert this piece of code before, because there is no declared 'watch' task before config loading.

Any ideas how to do implement it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used renameTask, so I can't speak to that, but we do this through registerTask.  In your case, you would want to use the line

```
grunt.registerTask('delta', ['watch']);
```

The other benefit of registerTask is that you can then assign one task to do multiple things (ie test might build, jshint, and scsslint).

Comment: Thank you for reply, but in this case, if i will register after that task named 'watch' and it will fire 'delta' (and maybe something else), then i will get in infinite loop.

Comment: When you don't have the renameTask line in, can you run watch?  And I see where you would get an infinite loop with registerTask from the aliases.js file